# Please Help to change font in equation [using system font]

Tags: fonts

I everyone. I'm new in this community.

I'm looking for help to change font in LaTeX. I will explain it :)

I write a document with Indesign and I use an OpenType police [Din 16]. I try since 2 days to use this font in LaTeX. I'm pretty new with this environment and changing font it's very hard...

I use TeXMaker on Windows compile with XeLaTeX, trying a lot of things but for the moment no solution. I read a lot from this website make a lot of test PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX but nothing that can solve my problem.

I hope you can help me !!

here a sample with PdfLatex:

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{8}\check@mathfonts $f\colon x \longmapsto 3(x + 2)^2 + 1$\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Another one with XeLatex :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setromanfont[Numbers=Uppercase]{Din16 Normal}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.90,Ligatures=NoCommon]{Courier}

\begin{document}
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{12}\check@mathfonts $f\colon x \longmapsto 3(x + 2)^2 + 1$\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I just find a way using XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Din16-Itl.otf}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
$f\colon x \longmapsto 3(x + 2)^2 + 1$
\end{document}
```

Just replace your system font "Din16-Itl.otf" by the one you want

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal document (code) which shows what you are trying to do. Whether you can use the font in question for mathematics depends heavily on the font's coverage and configuration. It may not have the symbols you need, for example.

Comment: Thanks for a so quickly answer I just write a sample code

Comment: So is this solved? If so, it would be better to put your solution in an answer. (It is OK to answer your own question.)